# Best way to output html via blade in Laravel, with XSS protection

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I need to output some html from database, which was filled by users via CKEeditor. So it may have some `<script>alert('something');</script>` or some other stuff. If i escape html output via blade `{{ $news->body }}` - i will get html as plain text which is not what i need. But if i use `{!! $news->body !!}` i will get normal html with working alert. Is there any clean way to deal with it?

Comment: You could use [PHP's strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). This will allow you to only include certain tags in your output.
`{!! strip_tags($news->body, ['<p><b><em>']) !!}`

Comment: Probably using [HTMLPurifier](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier) would be nice soulution. Worth checking out. I bet you'll find proper laravel package for htmlpurifier as well.

Comment: From the doc: By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks Jared Rolt it works perfect, only it should be {!! strip_tags($news->body, '<p><b><em>') !!} strip_tags second parameter is string. Nice and easy way. But i think that HTML Purifier will be more clean way, here is what i found about it https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/htmlpurifier-in-laravel-5?page=1 Thank you, Skysplit.

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5 and later there is [Purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier) which integrates the aforementioned [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) nicely into Laravel.

Install it using `composer require mews/purifier` and then use

```php
{!! clean($news->body) !!}
```

to output HTML that has been properly escaped with the default HTMLPurifier settings.